# Unable to change column size

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my database table, I've column `entryId` with data type varchar and size=10. Now I want to change size to 100, when I hit following query -

```
ALTER TABLE ft ALTER COLUMN entryId TYPE varchar(100);
```

it results into following error -

```
Incorrect syntax near 'varchar'.
```

My query syntax looks correct. Help me to understand what I did wrong.

Comment: ALTER TABLE ft ALTER COLUMN entryId varchar(100);

Comment: This is a nice page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No "Type" is need here:

```
ALTER TABLE ft ALTER COLUMN entryId varchar(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

I SQL Server, the keyword type is not needed

```
ALTER TABLE ft ALTER COLUMN entryId varchar(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

no need for 'TYPE' keyword

```
  ALTER TABLE ft ALTER COLUMN entryId varchar(100);
```

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.

Comment: actually we gave answer at same time duration. Please check the time at which we both posted our answer.

Comment: It's still lacking any explanation of what the asker did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Remove 'Type' from your query :

```
 ALTER TABLE ft ALTER COLUMN entryId VARCHAR(100);
```